# When returning a while loop back to the menu. the input question stays forever when trying to create a "Go back" button

Tags: python

So I am making a simple program in python (which I am very new to), and it is a simple menu with 4 options.

One of the options is used to display the users from a text file, and then it will ask the user if they want to return to the main menu. If they enter yes, my intention is to return the user to the main menu and continue from there, and if no, then it will just be passed.

The problem is, when the user inputs `"Y"` to return back to the main menu, it will take the user there, but the same "go back" input question will be asked continuously in the loop.

How do I break this? I am trying to make it so that when the user selects "Y" for go back, it will take them to the main menu, and ask the user which option they want to pick again.

Side note: If possible, it would mean a lot if someone could also tell me how to add drop down lines, so that, my program that reads a text file of usernames will then display each individual user as a drop down list in the program.

Code:

```
elif option == 4:
    print("\n" + "Displaying users... ")
    userlist = open('userlist.txt', 'r')
    f = userlist.readlines()    
    newList = []
    for line in f:
        if line[-1] == '\n':
            newList.append(line[:-1])
        else:
            newList.append(line)
    print(newList)
    while True:
        goback = input("Go back? (Y/N): ")
        if goback == "Y":
            menu()
        elif goback == "N":
            pass
        else:
            print ("Invalid option")
```

The area I am struggling with is:

```
goback = input("Go back? (Y/N): ")
if goback == "Y":
    menu()
```

As I want it to take me back to the main menu entirely instead of asking the same question over and over.

I have tried to get it to display the main menu without the input, but I am not really too sure how to do this. I have addded `menu()` to take the user back to the main menu, where they are able to select an option again. I have tried following up `menu()` with my prompt question
`option = int(input("Enter your option: "))`
but did not have any success, as when I entered an option, it went back to the same `"go back?"` question.

Comment: I think I should mention, my main menu uses a while loop to prompt the user to answer with an option until they give a correct answer. When the user inputs a correct answer, say, the option here, it then asks them if they want to go back or not, like a back button.

Comment: I think you should break the loop after `menu()`, just add a `break` statement in the next line

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra Thanks a lot! This fixed the issue completely!

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra One more thing, if I use break, then when I select "N" as the no option, it will take me back to the main menu anyway, how do I fix this?

Comment: you need to write the break statement in the `if goback == "Y"` block, code in the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is already there in comments so, code:

```
while True:
    goback = input("Go back? (Y/N): ")
    if goback == "Y":
        menu()
        break
    elif goback == "N":
        pass # Write code according to the action
    else:
        print ("Invalid option")
```

Output:

```
Displaying users... 
Go back? (Y/N): 
N
Go back? (Y/N): 
N
Go back? (Y/N): 
N
Go back? (Y/N): 
Y
```

Ends here because it is just a snippet

Comment: The only issue with this is that, when I select "N", I just want it to re-ask the question until the user says "Y", but if "N" is entered, it will break and go back to the main menu like if I entered "Y", any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that is what it does, I tried it

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer if it works :)

Comment: Although in this case, `pass` and `continue` would work the same way but one should use `continue` for iterating the next loop(as it's a good practice).

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Actually, the code would work fine even without the `elif` block, though I used `pass` because it is usually the indicator of a temporarily empty block and this code might be changed in the future.